# Write lines to a .dat file in a loop (MATLAB)

Tags: database, matlab, loops, format, printf

I am trying to create a .dat file with a specific format as to be read into a new program. In a loop, I open data and want to print that data to a new line in the .dat file. The output will look something like this:

```
Event #1 Jan 07 2001

file #1 00 11 22 33

file #2 01 12 23 34

..
```

So I want to combine strings and doubles obtained from a dataset to the same line of the .dat file. Here is the general form of my code now.

```
file=fopen('phase.dat', 'w');

for k=1:length(data)

X=data(1,k);

Y=data(2,k);

fprintf(file, '%s %f %f \n', 'Event 1', X, Y);

end

fclose(file);
```

This is not working however. Can you see my problem? Thanks,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit with my question - I've updated it. What I've written just isn't working. I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: "Not working" isn't much more helpful than not asking a question at all. I'm going to guess that your issue is with events not being appended, which is because you're using the [`'w'` file permission](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-permission), which overwrites the existing contents of the file when you open it with `fopen`, instead of `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
% Generate sample data...
data = randi([0 99],2,randi([5 10],1));
event = 12;

% Call fopen with permission A (opens or creates a file for writing, appending data)...
fid = fopen('phase.dat','a');

% Write the event header...
fprintf(fid,'Event #%d %s\n',event,datestr(now(),'mmm dd yyyy'));

% Write the event data...
for k = 1:size(data,2)
    fprintf(fid,'file #%d %02d %02d\n',k,data(1,k),data(2,k));
end

% Close the file handler...
fclose(fid);
```

Here is the potential content of the file after four runs:

```
Event #11 May 01 2018
file #1 84 63
file #2 51 88
file #3 81 80
file #4 23 89
file #5 23 14
file #6 50 79
file #7 29 46
file #8 00 74
file #9 03 56
file #10 05 02

Event #12 May 01 2018
file #1 23 70
file #2 28 36
file #3 37 47
file #4 96 74
file #5 54 31
file #6 75 11
file #7 50 20
file #8 17 47

Event #13 May 01 2018
file #1 93 01
file #2 32 14
file #3 27 80
file #4 94 56
file #5 59 69

Event #14 May 01 2018
file #1 85 52
file #2 57 12
file #3 22 02
file #4 99 45
file #5 72 62
file #6 56 95
file #7 44 58
file #8 44 00
file #9 83 73
```

You can adjust your spacing according to your needs by appending further `\n` at the end of the `fprintf` call formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. I did a small modification just to resemble your required format.

```
file=fopen('phase.dat', 'w');
fprintf(file, '%s\n\n', 'Event #1 Jan 07 2001');
data = rand(2,10);
for k=1:length(data)

    X=data(1,k);

    Y=data(2,k);

    fprintf(file, '%s%d %f %f\n\n', 'file #', k, X, Y);

end

fclose(file);
```

So, what exactly is not working?